# Rails: Searching multiple tables from one query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

How do I write condition statement in `find` or `paginate` method to allow users search in `Project` and `Project Category` names simultaneously?

Now my code looks like this

```
@projects = Project.paginate :per_page => 20, :page => params[:page], :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{params[:search]}%"]
```

So I have also `Category` table with `name` field. How do I combine those two `name`s together in this search query?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that your `Project` model `has_many :categories`:

> `@projects = Project.paginate :per_page => 20, :page => params[:page], :joins => :categories, :conditions => ['projects.name LIKE ? OR categories.name LIKE ?', "%#{params[:search]}%", "%#{params[:search]}%"], :order => 'projects.id DESC'`

Change the `:order` above if/as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
@categories = Category.find :conditions => ["name like ?", "%#{params[:search]}%"]
```

Concatenate @projects and @categories, and then use the result as the final search result list.